# Using grep on 2 list files

Tags: list, file, design-patterns, grep

I have 2 files
file1 contains list of patterns I need to grep 
eg:

```
abc
bcd
def
```

file2 contains names of the files along with absolute path
eg:

```
/prod/users/abc/username/filename1.dat
/prod/users/abc/username/filename2.dat
/prod/users/abc/username/filename3.dat
```

I have to grep

```
abc in /prod/users/abc/username/filename1.dat
bcd in /prod/users/abc/username/filename2.dat
def in /prod/users/abc/username/filename3.dat
```

Can anyone help me here with the UNIX code.
the following does not work

```
for i in `cat file2`
do
  for j in `file1`
  do
  cat -n $i| grep $j >> file_final.txt
  done
done
```

Comment: Avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this:  `for i in $(cat file2)`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a `cat` in

```
for j in `file1`
```

change it to

```
for j in `cat file1`
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested loops make it look like you're trying to search each pattern on each file.

Perhaps you mean something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
patterns=`cat file1`
values=(`cat file2`)
for pattern in ${patterns}
do
  cat -n ${values[i]} | grep $pattern >> file_final.txt
  ((i++))
done
```

Incidentally, grep provides a `-n` option, so you don't need to `cat` out your file; you can just grep on it:

```
grep $pattern -n ${values[i]} >> file_final.txt
```